# Java program does not terminate after jsch ssh client executes command

Tags: java, ssh

I am using java ssh client (http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/) to connect to remote machine and execute the command. The code is working fine till i connect to remote machine and execute the command. however, the issue is , the channel and session are not getting disconnected even after command executed successfully.

I have called session.disconnect and channel.disconnect as well but still the issue.

Here is my code:

```
JSch jsch = new JSch();
String privateKey = "C:\\test\\key";
jsch.addIdentity(privateKey);
String host = null;
host = "192.168.102.211";
Session session = jsch.getSession("chef-admin", host, 22);
Channel channel = session.openChannel("shell");
try
{

    String cmd = "sudo su";
    String command = "chef-client";


    UserInfo ui = new MyUserInfo() {
        public boolean promptYesNo(String message) {
            return true;
        }
    };
    session.setUserInfo(ui);
    session.connect(30000);

    OutputStream ops = channel.getOutputStream();
    PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(ops, true);

    channel.connect();
    ps.println(cmd);
    ps.println(command);
    ps.close();

    InputStream in = channel.getInputStream();
    byte[] bt = new byte[1024];
        while (in.available() > 0) {
            int i = in.read(bt, 0, 1024);
            if (i < 0)
                break;
            String str = new String(bt, 0, i);
            System.out.println("valueeeeeeeeeeeeeeee is " + i);
            System.out.print(str);

    }

        System.out.println("before channel");

    }
catch (Exception e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
finally
{
     if (channel != null) {
         System.out.println("finally");
            channel.disconnect();
            session.disconnect();
            System.out.println(channel.isConnected());
        }
}
```

Comment: did your `while(in.available()>0)` finish?  is it a infinite loop?

Comment: i guess yes that is the issue. but how to end that loop. ?? I am all dependent on the InputStream to be finished. Once it is finish , while loop should stop and come out . but that is what is not happening

Comment: it doesnt reach the end of stream yet.

Comment: Is it running on Unix or Windows? There's a hack in the example in the documentation that supplies a FilteredInputStream for Windows instead. May be needed to ensure closure of the stream. http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/examples/Shell.java.html

Comment: so whats the solution then for this ? can you please suggest some code changes so that it can work ? please

Comment: my eclipse IDE is on windows as of now

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jsch java ssh client is not getting disconnected after command gets executed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36151893/jsch-java-ssh-client-is-not-getting-disconnected-after-command-gets-executed)

Comment: Please don't [repost your question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36151893/13317).

Comment: i added the finally block as well in the code .. however, it is still not working ....